# Toyota Master and Valet Keys don't work

Tags: toyota, key, yaris

Three weeks ago I went to a 2 weeks bussines trip and I lost my key (master, with controls) the day I went to the airport but I noticed it until I came back home last saturday. The vehicle (Toyota Yaris 2015) has been parked since. I got the other master key (black) and the valet key (grey) but both failed. Both enter completely but dont turn right nor left.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I have a stupid question: Are you sure the car you were trying is yours?

Comment: There are not stupid questions, only stupids that do not ask! And yes, it is my car.

Comment: I left the car at home when I went to the airport.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you left the car at the airport ... my misunderstanding.

Comment: Is it not turning in the steering column (ignition switch) or in the door? If it's in the steering column, just try giggling the steering wheel while you try to turn the key.

Comment: Both the door and ignition switch.

Comment: Have you ever used these keys in the car?

Comment: Possible dead battery?